# Google Script testing add-on, unable to load file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I've been making simple scripts in Google Docs and Sheets for a couple of years, but now I'm trying to convert some of it to an add-on. I think I should test the add-on before I publish it and send it to review.

In the scripting window i click: Run > Test as add-on.

I choose another document for testing, but when I hit the blue test-button I get an error message: "Unable to load file. Try load it again or send an error report."

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Fzj.png)

I may open the document manually. I've tried with several different files and scripts. Same error.

I hope you may give me a clue to the cause of this. I'm using Firefox 57.0.4 (64-bits) and a private Google account.

Comment: Use Chrome not Firefox.  Check to see if Chrome is the latest version. Close your browser and reboot your computer.  Delete the setting for the file, and load a different file.  This isn't a programming question, so it's "Off topic" to Stack Overflow.  It would have been better to ask the question at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) Or the [Developing add-ons for G Suite](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494) Community.

Comment: Thank you! Chrome worked (kind of embarrassed I didn't try that...).

Also thank you for the posting advise, I will check those other places :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using Chrome works! I also rebooted the computer, but didn't have to delete settings etc.